# Using the pointer returned from a std::shared_ptr<T>.get() function to delete an object?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<int>();
    auto p = sp.get();
    delete p; //here
    std::cout << *sp << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was hoping that the object managed by the `shared_ptr sp` will be deleted by the statement commented "here" but the object remains intact and is printed in the output statement.

- Is this not working because I didn't create the object managed by the `shared_ptr` explicitly with the `new` keyword (because every `new` statement must have a corresponding `delete` statement and therefore every `delete` statement, an earlier corresponding `new` keyword?)?
- And does this mean that pointed objects managed by `shared_ptr`s, created from the `make_shared` function are destroyed only by the `shared_ptr`s themselves?

Comment: Don't use a smart pointer, and then try to manage the memory for it. That defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: `shared_ptr` will delete the object for you. You are first dereferencing a dangling pointer and then doubly deleting the object because the destructor of `shared_ptr` also will delete the pointer.

Comment: C++ will gladly let you shoot yourself in the foot. The performant option for the compiler is usually to carry on and assume you didn't do anything bad. You can use tools such as sanitizers (address sanitizer in this case) to take the less performant option of detecting this sort of thing and getting a loud complaint about it from the tool.

Comment: @octopus `delete` marks the memory occupied by the object as "free to be re-used" and calls the objects destructor. After `delete` you are *not allowed* (under pain of invoking UB) to ever access the object again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shared_ptr` doesn't know you `delete` the pointer you got from `.get()`. So when the `shared_ptr` itself is destroyed it will *also* try to *delete* the object - leading to a double delete which is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Additionally, dereferencing a pointer to a deleted object is *also* UB.

`delete` marks the memory occupied by the object as "free to be re-used" and calls the objects destructor. After `delete` you are *not allowed* (under pain of invoking UB) to ever access the object again.

Your program is simply invalid and *anything* the compiler may generate is allowed.

Comment: @octopus Undefined behavior means that you have no guarantee whatsoever for the program behavior. It may seem to work, it may crash, it may give random output, anything. A crash or error is in no way guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The way to "manage" the memory associated with a `shared_ptr` is to use C++ scoping, often referred to [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) (**R**esource **A**cquisition **I**s **I**nitialization).

For your code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    {
       auto sp = std::make_shared<int>();
       std::cout << *sp << std::endl;
    }
    // memory is now delete'd because "sp" is out-of-scope

    return 0;
}
```

With `shared_ptr` things can actually be (quite a bit) more complicated than that as multiple `shared_ptr`s can be pointing to the same memory; only when the *last* one is gone is the memory deleted.

Your preference should be to use `std::unique_ptr` until you really need `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you do this your object will be deleted twice, and you'll crash if you're lucky.

Second, just because something has been deleted doesn't mean it's underlying representation is guaranteed to be invalid. You can have a situation where the memory is freed, but nothing has yet come around to overwrite what was there before.

Comment: (not downvoter) Probably because your answer could be misleading in that you make it seem that reading deleted memory may be allowed. It is never allowed to access deleted memory.